# Angular 6 . I Want to change the interval dynamically according to the value given in the array

Tags: angular6, setinterval

This is my set-interval and I want to change the interval dynamically according to the value given in the array.

```js
setInterval(() => {
    this.getwebsiteurl();

    this.count++;

    if (this.count > this.data1.length) {
        this.count = 0;
    }
}, this.filtered[this.count].timeout);

getwebsiteurl() {
    if (this.count < this.data1.length) {
        this.http
            .get("assets/" + this.len + "/" + this.data1[this.count].HtmlName + ".html", {
                responseType: "text"
            })

            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.htmlfile = data;
            });
    }
}
```

[Filtered Array contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERcUA.jpg)

Comment: The issue might be because your timeout is string its should be a number. Just make this.filtered[this.count].timeout +this.filtered[this.count].timeout and it should owrk

Comment: I tried but its not working for me @sah1